# Pi-Hole Redirecting Domain to IP

Tags: ubuntu, dns, dnsmasq, pi-hole

I have a domain that points to the external IP of my webserver. I set up a Pi-Hole server and changed my network settings to use it, and I've verified it is working. I want to redirect the URL of my webserver, which points to the external IP, to the internal IP of the webserver.

I used the command

```
sudo pihole -a hostrecord example.com 192.168.0.12
```

to redirect the domain to the IP. But when I try to connect to it through ping, nslookup, and using a browser it goes to the external IP.

I then did the command again, but this time with the domain misspelled.

```
sudo pihole -a hostrecord eexample.com 192.168.0.12
```

This time it worked and visiting eexample.com worked as expected and it was redirected to the correct IP.

I've cleared my computer's DNS cache and Pi-Hole's. Also, when I visited the correct domain on my phone (connected to the network and had mobile data turned off), which had never connected to the site before, it worked as expected.

What's going on?

Comment: Are you doing a upstream DNS server configuration and is the DNS in question also externally resolvable on the internet? If so it' the upstream that's serving your request for example.com, not the local definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avast Antivirus has a feature called "Real Site" where they silently force your computer to use their DNS servers to protect you against DNS hijacking. This overrides any custom DNS servers you have.

Disabling this fixed this. Go to Protection -> Real Site and disable it "Indefinitely".

- [Real Site Details](https://help.avast.com/en/av_free/11/etc_tools_secure_dns_overview.html)

Comment: Ugh what a waste of time for a stupid feature. I'm tempted to delete this since it has nothing to do with Unix/Linux at this point.

Comment: Please leave it for future people who have the same issue. There is no reason to delete it.

Comment: I was saying that more our of frustration, b/c your actual problem had nothing really to do w/ Unix and was a windows AV issue. I won't delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your issue is with that approach, I suspect you're falling prey to this issue titled: [Add host-record option #1266](https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole/pull/1266). **NOTE:** This feature seems to make little sense, since it only appears to allow for a single `host-record` entry.

But I'd just add the `host-record` entry that you want directly into dnsmasq's `/etc/dnsmasq.d/01-pihole.conf` config file, and by-pass Pi-Hole's odd feature implementation.

Simply add lines like so:

```
host-record=google.com,192.168.0.12
```

#### Example

Here I overrode www.google.com like so:

```
$ cat /etc/dnsmasq.d/01-pihole.conf
host-record=www.google.com,192.168.1.107
```

and then restart:

```
$ pihole restartdns
  [✓] Restarting DNS service
$
```

And confirm:

```
$ dig +short www.google.com
192.168.1.107
```

#### Something more permanent

If you're concerned about editing the `01-pihole.conf` file you can create your own set of files under `/etc/dnsmasq.d` to do whatever you want, without having them being impacted by updates to Pi-Hole. You could also use `03-pihole-wildcard.conf`, I do not believe this file will get impacted via updates.

I do something similar for my LAN so I can override things:

```
$ cat /etc/dnsmasq.d/03-pihole-wildcard.conf
address=/babycam.mydomain.com/192.168.2.1
address=/www.yahoo.com/192.168.2.10
```

Then do the `pihole restartdns` like above and confirm:

```
$ pihole restartdns
  [✓] Restarting DNS service

$ dig +short www.yahoo.com
192.168.2.10
```

#### References

- https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole/blob/master/advanced/01-pihole.conf
- [Don't automatically include all subdomains in DNSMasq address](https://serverfault.com/questions/431605/dont-automatically-include-all-subdomains-in-dnsmasq-address)
- [Add custom DNS entrees #975](https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole/issues/975)

Comment: The redirect is working and I can visit the URL on my phone and other computers that haven't visited the site before and each one is redirected to the correct IP. 

But it isn't working on my Windows computers that have visited , they think the URL is still pointing to the real IP of the domain and not the one that Dnsmasq is redirecting.

**What's going on? Why can't Windows get the new IP from the server?**

I've cleared the DNS cache on my computers.